# rospy getting two publishers

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have a two or more nodes publishing in the diagnostic topic.

```
roman@roman-virtual-machine1:~/nagios$ rostopic info diagnostics
Type: diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray

Publishers: 
 * /mobile_base_nodelet_manager (http://roman-virtual-machine1:35669/)
 * /play_1410810684593700345 (http://roman-virtual-machine1:40540/)
```

I am trying to read all Publishers information but when I use rospy I get only one Publisher at the time.

```
def listener():
    #rospy.init_node('check_battery_kobuki', anonymous=True,  disable_signals=True, log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
    rospy.init_node('ros_diagnostics', anonymous=True,  disable_signals=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("diagnostics", DiagnosticArray , callback_kobuki)
    rospy.spin()
```

Is there a way to get all Publishers in the same connection ?

Thanks in advance,
Felipe Roman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193256/rospy-getting-two-publishers/) by [felipe.roman](https://answers.ros.org/users/20268/felipe.roman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short: no.

The unit of transport in ROS is a message, and publishers are anonymous, so it doesn't make sense to ask which publisher a message came from. Publishers aren't required to publish at the same or with the same frequency either, so it doesn't make sense to deliver the data from all publishers simultaneously.

If you're trying to aggregate diagnostics data, you may want to look at the [diagnostic_aggregator](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_aggregator) and either use it, or implement a similar algorithm in your own code.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1